# Links offset on my page

Tags: links

For some reason, the links for my nav bar are offset so they start much lower than normal. The buttons seem to be in the right place, but for some reason the links themselves are rendering in a different place.

When the admin bar is out, the nav bar moves so the buttons are in the same place as the links, and the links take up the whole button, but when the admin bar retracts, the links do not extend below the admin bar.

It looks like this is not a problem with the CSS, and the link is linked to the button and not separate.

Where can I look to find this problem so the links move?

Comment: It's definitely a CSS issue or conflict. Did you try deactivating the plugins? What theme are you using?

Comment: @Ciprian thanks, I'll look into this when I get to work tomorrow.